# Clear file before writing new content into it (Java, Android)

Tags: java, android

I'm using the following code to create a new file (binary or JSON) or rewrite an existing one in Android:

```
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = this.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "w");
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
fileOutputStream.write(bytes);
fileOutputStream.close();
pfd.close();
```

The problem is when the file already exists and its content size is larger, the old content remains. E.g. JSON can look like

```
[
    "a",
    "b"
]   "c",
    "d"
]
```

How do I clean the file before writing into it, or clear the remaining content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `"wt"` instead of `w`, to truncate the file (`t`) before writing to it.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the delay, switching to SDK 29 from SDK 23 was painful. Another question for you :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64787929/prevent-extension-prefix-1-when-saving-a-file-on-android

Answer (score 3):

you should change the initialization of `FileOutputStream` with a second parameter which say to overwrite the file content:

`FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor(), false);` second parameter if its `true` then it append while its `false` it will overwrite.

```
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = this.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "wt");
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
fileOutputStream.write(bytes);
fileOutputStream.close();
pfd.close();
```

Comment: Seems like `new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor(), false)` doesn't accept the second boolean argument (SDK 29).

Answer (score 2):

Access mode for the file:

```
 1. "r" for read-only access,
 2. "w" for write-only access (erasing whatever data is currently in the file),
 3. "wa" for write-only access to append to any existing data, 
 4. "rw" for read and write access on any existing data, 
 5."rwt" for read and write access that truncates any existing file.
```

Try rwt it may do the job