# Prevent extension prefix (1) when saving a file on Android

Tags: java, android

I'm using the following code to let users save a file on Android:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, fileName);
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

where `fileName` is something like "Drawing 1.ink". The problem is when a file with the same name already exists, a user is suggested to save a new file under "Drawing 1.ink (1)" name. People often save files with "ink (1)" extension.

How to prevent this and make a default suggested file name like "Drawing 1 (1).ink"? Or forcing a suggested name without "(1)"?

Comment: `when a file with the same name already exists, a user is suggested ...` I have never seen any suggestion. If the user clicks ok a new file is made with (#) appended.

Comment: Before you launch the intent check if the file name is allready in use.  Well.. that was my first thought. But.. you dont know the directory the user would choose in advance..

Comment: If you want to have full control over file name then let user choose directory instead.

Comment: @blackapps I want to have control over file extension, file name can be prefixed.

Comment: Yes i know. Not possible i think. So i came with a different action/solution. You did not tell why you would not use that.

Comment: @blackapps I think that users are used to saving a file rather than choosing a directory. Also, what happens if the file with the same name already exists, but user don't want to rewrite it?

Comment: Dont understand the scenario. I proposed to generate a new name yourself if a file name is already in use. And which user is not able to choose a directory or a file? Does not make any difference i think.

Comment: @blackapps Thanks for the suggestion. I will try checking for a file before opening the Intent.

Comment: You realise that you only can check that if the user once choosed that directory with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMent_tree? (Or a parent from that directory).

Answer (score 1):

> How to prevent this

You can't.

> Or forcing a suggested name without "(1)"?

You can't.

> I want to have control over file extension

You can't.

This is a system-supplied UI, not significantly different from platform-supplied "file save-as" dialogs that we have used for decades. You're welcome to file feature requests to improve the available options here, though such changes would only take effect with Android 12 or some other future version.